# Rollback class after the click function

Tags: jquery

I have so many div inside the main div and It's difficult to select exactly that div.
Suppose like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div>
   <div></div>
   <div>
     <div>
       <div>
       <div class="myclass">
       </div>
.....
</div>
```

So with my markup I could select the class just with: `.myclass`

Firstly I've to remove it class `myclass` like this: `$('.myclass').removeClass('myclass');`

Next I've to add add the same class

So I tried like this:

```
$('.thisclass').addClass('myclass').removeClass('thisclass');
$('.myclass').addClass('thisclass').removeClass('myclass');
```

But inside the on/off click function

You can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEqE3/) which is not doing what I want.

So my key question is that how can I roll back the previous class after the on click function. I need to remove the previous class and **after the click**.

> just like mouseenter and mouseleave but I extremly need after on('click')

Comment: Can you explain how you want to use this ? It looks like an "I want A, I thought of B, I ask B" question.

Comment: @LeGEC Read the answers below, all are confused

Comment: exactly my slider is having no animation first when the click event occurs then it should animate to left and again callback the class which would stop the animation.

Comment: Can you update your question, following the lines : "I have a slider, the html looks like that, I want this to happen, I have tried that" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this :

```
$('#clickthis').on('click', function(){
    $('.thisclass').addClass('myclass').removeClass('thisclass');

//call this function later, after the 'click' event has been handled :
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.myclass').addClass('thisclass').removeClass('myclass');
    }, 0);
});
```

---

You should not use `setTimeout`, you should use the `complete` callback of the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) function :

```
$(...).animate( ...,  function(){
    //this function will be called once the animation is finished

    $('.myclass').addClass('thisclass').removeClass('myclass');
    // add any action you want to take on animation's end
})
```

All of jQuery's [effect functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) (e.g : [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), etc ...) accept a `complete` callback.

Comment: wait I'll test for my site.

Comment: no its not working .... exactly my slider is having no animation first when the click event occurs then it should animate to left and again callback the class which would stop the animation.

Comment: I was animating my div with one second so I replaced 0 with 1000 which worked but the animation was effected badly

Comment: So can I position the div to left -1094px but careful is that div is static

Comment: I think I should ask this question in new

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
$('#clickthis').on('click', function(){
    $('.thisclass, .myclass').toggleClass('myclass thisclass');

});
```

check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QEqE3/3/)

Comment: NO, its not toggle function that I need , but when clicked immidiately the previous class should be back again.

Comment: it's coming with the previous class once i clicked on, not getting what you're asking for

Comment: when u click again then only its doing so but immediately after the click