# How can I position to static div on button click?

Tags: jquery

When the button is clicked it should be positioned to `left: -1094px;` but careful is that the div must be static.
So can I set position to -1094px to that div anyway for the div with position static?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: In relation with this question I've asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998766/rollback-class-after-the-click-function

Comment: **Position** to what `Button` or `div` **(button is clicked it should be positioned)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element has

```
position: static;
```

adding `left` property (as well as `right`, `top`, `bottom`) doesn't affect it. You can try with

```
margin-left: -1094px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning elements is covered [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

> If a div is a static element it is not effected by the
>   top,left,bottom,right css properties.
>
> If a div is a relative element it is effected by the
>   top,left,bottom,right properties but in relation to the parent
>   container, i.e. the parent div.
>
> If a div is an absolute element it is effected by the
>   top,left,bottom,right properties and is positioned in relation to the first parent 
>   element to have a position other than static
>
> If a div is fixed it is effected by the top,left,bottom,right
>   properties and is positioned in relation to the browser window.

Hope this helps.